# Swift backgroundColor comparison not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When programmatically adding background color to UIButton to system green `sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen` it sets the backgroundColor to SystemGreen, yet when I check it with this if/else statement

```
if(sender.backgroundColor == UIColor.systemGreen)
{
   doSomething()
}
else 
{
   otherThing()
}
```

doSomething() is not called, and code goes to the else statement. Why?

Comment: print `sender.backgroundColor` and `UIColor.systemGreen` before the `if`? What's the output?

Comment: @kepler siguineau - can you show that `When programmatically adding background color to UIButton`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik like this ```sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen ```

Comment: @Larme This is what I'm getting with the print statement ```sender background: Optional(<UIDynamicModifiedColor: 0x6000007fc840; contrast = normal, baseColor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600001cc5a40; name = systemGreenColor>>) 
 UIColor.systemGreen: <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600001cc5a40; name = systemGreenColor>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this

Step 1: Set the background of UIButton in viewdidload

```
@IBOutlet weak var currentBtn: UIButton!
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        currentBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBrown
    }
```

step 2: compare the two colours with help of [cgcolour](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor) in the button action, its works fine for me, please check your end too.

```
@IBAction func checkButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let getColour = sender.backgroundColor, getColour.cgColor == UIColor.systemBrown.cgColor{
           print("comes here")
        }else {
            print("not here")
        }
    }
```